# Python: Trying to identify specific row/column in csv and store it as a variable, then print to a txt file in a sentence.

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to this. This is what I currently have:

```
import csv

input_file = open('linklist.csv', 'rb')
output_file = open('Link Statements9.txt', 'wb')

reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)

for row in reader:
writer.writerow(row)
```

This takes the information entered in a csv and prints it to a txt, but I would like to take the information from a specific space on the csv (row 3, column 2 for example) and store it as a string so I can do other things with it and I can't find how specifically to do that.

The idea is that I enter the following in a csv:

```
MPP01, Unit 1, Unit 2, 14336
```

And have the following print to a text document:

```
Establish link MPP01 at 14336 Kbps to Unit 2.
Terminate link MPP01 at 14336 Kbps from Unit 1.
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be welcome.

Comment: if you want to output text, why are you using a CSV writer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it; there is no need to use a CSV writer if you want to output just text.

```
import csv

with open('linklist.csv', 'rb') as input_file, \
        open('Link Statements9.txt', 'w') as output_file:

    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
        link_name, from_unit, to_unit, rate = row
        output_file.write("Establish link %s at %s Kbps to Unit %s.\n"
                          % (link_name, rate, to_unit))
        output_file.write("Establish link %s at %s Kbps from Unit %s.\n"
                          % (link_name, rate, from_unit))
```

Note that I'm using the `with open(...) as ...:` construct for dealing with files to ensure they always get closed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you want to turn objects into a formatted string, you should use the `.format` method. Each row in `reader` takes the form of a list of strings, so you can very easily insert them into a format string. For example, if you have a csv row as you described you can use it like this:

```
row = ['MPP01', 'Unit 1', 'Unit 2', '14336']

formatted_row = ('Establish link {0} at {3} Kbps to {2}.\n' +
                 'Terminate link {0} at {3} Kbps to {1}.\n').format(*row)
```

The `*row` represents unpacking the variable, as if you had called `.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])`

Second, if you're writing to a text file, not a csv file, you don't want to use `csv.writer`, but should just write to the file directly.

```
with open('Link Statements9.txt', 'wb') as output_file:
    for row in reader:
        output_file.write(('Establish link {0} at {3} Kbps to {2}.\n' +
                           'Terminate link {0} at {3} Kbps to {1}.\n').format(*row)
```

If you only want to act on certain numbered rows, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for index, row in enumerate(reader):
    # make decision based on index here
```

Finally, you should probably use the `with` statement rather than opening files directly (it's easier), but if you do open them directly, remember to close them when you're done.

The whole script:

```
import csv

with open('linklist.csv', 'rb') as input_file, open('Link Statements9.txt', 'wb') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        output_file.write(('Establish link {0} at {3} Kbps to {2}.\n' +
                           'Terminate link {0} at {3} Kbps to {1}.\n').format(*row))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but when I tried it out it printed the output all on one line. I tried to use a \n but that didn't work when I inserted it after the '{2}.' Any idea how I could accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would print everything on one line, but the way it was was wrong. I forgot to remove the leading spaces from the string, so the second line would have been too far indented. The way I changed it to should be clearer.